# Fibonacci even sum in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm, fibonacci

so i previously posted a question on writing a code in where:
  Starting at 1, print all the even Fibonacci numbers up to 10946 (inclusive)

Print a sum of all the numbers you printed.

You must use a loop

You must use a conditional branch for testing even/odd
i realized i was doing it all wrong so i rewrote my code and came up with this

```
.equ Stdout, 1 
.equ SWI_Exit, 0x11 
.global _start
.text
_start:

MOV R2,#0 @Starting value of 0 to register 1
MOV R3,#1 @starting val of 1 to register 2




LOOP: 
LDR R4,=10946 @register gets this value
ODDCHECK:
CMP R4,R5
ADD R4,R2,R3 @adding to cehck if its odd

TST R4,#1
MOV R3,R2   @ answer is 0
MOV R2,R4   @result is in R4 adds to R2 is 0=1
BNE ODDCHECK
BEQ LOOP    @exiting the loop if it reaches final number
MOV R0,#Stdout
MOV R1,R5
SWI SWI_PrInt @Print out all the numbers
LDR R1, =NL 
SWI SWI_PrStr 

B LOOP

    After:
    SWI SWI_Exit
.data
NL: .asciz"\n"
```

this loads properly in ARM but it does nothing when i run it. Now my question is am i checking if the number is even and then printing it in my code? as well as am i printing out the sum of all the even numbers? I am very new to this assembly language stuff, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `BNE ODDCHECK` / `BEQ LOOP` <-- one of those jumps will _always_ be taken. Also, you've got weird things like `CMP R4,R5` where you A) haven't initialized `R5` and B) aren't using the flags set by `CMP` for anything.

Answer (score 3):

The community can answer your specific question, but a better solution is to help you develop some debugging skills.  When something doesn't work, you need to drill down and find out where the failure is.  Since you're new to ARM assembly, try doing small chunks at a time and then putting them together to form the complete program.

Can you write a program that prints a number?

Can you write a loop that prints a series of numbers (such as a loop counter)?

Can you write a loop that prints the fibonnaci sequence?

Can you write a loop that prints the even fibonacci numbers?

Let us know at which step you're failing and why.